# Descriptive function of motion of a rigid rod around an axis and, by analogy, around a cylinder and the volume "swept" from it

Tags: functions

I kindly ask for your help for the "rust" that, after many years of mathematical inactivity, I have regarding the schematization of physical problems.

Problem, as from the title, concerns the need to find a 3D function that describes the volume generated by a rigid auction of unitary length that moves around a cylindrical guide of radius R, and height (vertical) greater than 1, starting from vertical position (i.e. attacked in parallel to the cylindrical driving i.e. 90 'with respect to the horizontal plane) and ending its motion, after all of lap corner around the guide, in a horizontal position (i.e. at 0' compared to the horizontal).

The motion is characterized by a constant and continuous reduction of the angle of inclination with respect to the horizontal plane.

[image]

Comment: This is not very clear. What is a rigid auction and what is a cylindrical guide?

Comment: Brown is auction, rod: brown; guide: blue
you can also see the problem in a different form or rather a rigid rod that moves in a spiral trajectory one end placed on the horizontal plane, and the other rests necessarily on a cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what sort of "function" you want. But trying to clarify that without examples looks hard to accomplish. So I am putting out one interpretation.

Assuming your rod is actually a line segment, the points it "sweeps through" form a surface, with area, but no volume. Surfaces are two-dimensional. It takes two numbers to specify any point on them. so the domain of the function needs to be some subset of $\Bbb R^2$. The shape exists in three dimensions so the codomain of the function is $\Bbb R^3$.

To figure out such a function, we need to find a way of identifying any given point $P$ on the surface using two values. An obvious choice would be for one coordinate to be the counter-clockwise angle $\theta$ about the origin from the positive $y$-axis to the projection of the point into the $xy$-plane. As you make a full circle, this runs from $0$ to $2\pi$. And for the second coordinate to be the distance $s$ to the point along the rod to the end where it touches the cylinder. This runs from $0$ to $L$.

So the domain is $[0,2\pi] \times [0,L]$. You say the angle $\phi$ of inclination decreases as a constant rate from $\frac \pi 2$ to $0$ as the rod sweeps around. Hence it would be given by $\phi = \frac{2\pi - \theta}4 = \frac \pi 2 - \frac \theta 4$. In the plane through $P$ containing the $Z$ axis, the rod would therefore have slope $\cot \phi = \cot\left(\frac \pi 2 - \frac \theta 4\right) = \tan\frac \theta 4$. In this plane, the rod forms the hypotenuse a right triangle with the intersections of this plane with the cylinder and the $xy$-plane. The height of the triangle is $L\sin \frac\theta 4$ and the base is $L\cos\frac\theta 4$.The top of the rod = the top of the triangle will be the point $\left(R\sin\theta, R\cos\theta, L\sin\frac\theta 4\right)$. As we move away from it, the $z$ coordinate reduces linearly from $L\sin\frac\theta 4$ to $0$, while the horizontal distance increases linearly from $R$ to $R + L\cos\frac\theta 4$.

This means the desired function is $$\begin{align}F :\ &[0,2\pi] \times [0,L] \to \Bbb R^3 \\:\ &(\theta, s) \mapsto \bigg(\left(R + s\cos\frac\theta 4\right)\sin \theta, \left(R + s\cos\frac\theta 4\right)\cos \theta, (L - s)\sin\frac\theta 4\bigg)\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, you're right I expressed myself very badly. The request is in fact unique but concerns two problems: the description of the motion (rational mechanics) and the integral of the volume underlying by the auction.
Anyway thanks many!

Comment: First, the only English definition of "auction" that most people are familiar with is a sale where potential buyers bid on the item and the one with the highest bid gets to buy it. And "rational" mechanics is also not a well-known phrase in English, though there I can assume it refers to "kinematics" (though only the well-grounded in physics will readily understand that word). You haven't described the motion well-enough to come up with a definitive answer. But if one adds the assumption the angular velocity of $\theta$ is constant, then just replacing $\theta$ by $\omega t$ in $F$ works.

Comment: ... yes ... thank very much ... I have nothing to add to what you wrote to me. 
I just have to learn!
Thanks again Paul and Happy Easter!